# Missing file in / taking up all of the root space

Tags: linux, centos, kvm-virtualization

I was copying a large VM disk file to a separate larger separate disk array to work on it and during a benchmark I did previously before I started the copy job I didn't realize that the benchmark had unmounted the array. So the file was partially copied to somewhere within the `/` filesystem and I cannot find it anywhere. I've looked with some commands like `find -type f -exec du -Sh {} + | sort -rh | head -n 5` to the find the largest files. Any suggestions? Below are the file system outputs.

```
df -h
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos-root   50G   50G  122M 100% /
devtmpfs                  16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs                     16G     0   16G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                     16G   11M   16G   1% /run
tmpfs                     16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2               1014M  216M  799M  22% /boot
/dev/sda1                200M   12M  189M   6% /boot/efi
/dev/mapper/centos-home  864G  301G  563G  35% /home
tmpfs                    3.1G   32K  3.1G   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sdb1                1.9T  132G  1.7T   8% /disk1


du -sh *
0       bin
194M    boot
0       dev
46G     disk1
41M     etc
301G    home
0       lib
0       lib64
0       media
0       mnt
720K    opt
du: cannot access ‘proc/39152/task/39152/fd/3’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘proc/39152/task/39152/fdinfo/3’: No such file ordirectory
du: cannot access ‘proc/39152/fd/3’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘proc/39152/fdinfo/3’: No such file or directory
0       proc
4.9M    root
du: cannot access ‘run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied
11M     run
0       sbin
0       srv
0       sys
20M     tmp
3.5G    usr
673M    var
```

Comment: Your output is nearly useless (you only show one file system, not all mounted ones and we can't make out the type of the entries in your list. Check what `disk1` is, this is a strange name not normally found in `/`.

Comment: disk1 is a second raid array with the identifier sdb1 and the mount point of /disk1. Under df -h centos-root is 100% full after the failed move like I said and /disk1 is is 8% with centos-home at 35%. I updated the main post to show all the filsystems if that helps.

Comment: Note that `/dev/mapper/centos-root == / but != /root` although `/` is called the *”root file system/partition”* it contains more than the /root directory

Comment: Yes, it contains /root, /etc, /run among others. /home is a separate partition and /disk1 is an entirely different disk array. I'm trying to find what I assume is a half moved vhdx file that wound up in / when it filled up after running the command the first time because of my mistake but I can't find any such file currently which leaves me wondering why that partition filled up and what filled it up since /disk1 is not included in it and is now larger than 700GB after I corrected my mistake.

Comment: You could relative easily find the largest files in any partition with a singleline script. For example (I did not test it): `find /mount/point -type f -print 0|xargs -P 1 -n 500 ls -l|sort -n -k +5 -r|head -20`. About your question, I would suggest to try to make it more specific, best if the answerers can see *already from its title*, what you want. If you ask a question, tune it always to the time of the answerer. If your problem don't get a reopen, you might also try https://unix.stackexchange.com . If it is reopened, you are not allowed to cross-post. It will be decided in roughly a day.

Comment: Thank you for the help :) I did actually try to use a similar find command that does the things as the one listed does and that's why I'm confused basically. All of the files that I can find are in `/disk1` which isn't part of `/`, it can't be because `/disk1` is over 700GB now with things i've been doing it in. Only things larger than 100M in side of the subfolders of `/` are 146M in `/var/lib/rpm/Packages` and 102M in `/usr/lib/locale`

Comment: The new disk array was unmounted during the benchmark I did which I didn't realize and when I started the file copy and it just partially copied the file to the folder I made inside of `/` as the mount point and filled up the space for `/`. It wasn't visible or even showing up in any command that would find the largest files in the file-system because the disk array was remounted over top of it. So after I unmounted it on purpose again to fix something I was able to find and delete it.

Answer (score 2):

You have 46G on `/disk1`, so unless that is another partition, that seems the place to look.

When I want to know where most of the space is used,I use this command:

```
du -Sx / | sort -n
```

If the used space isn't visible to `du`, then it belongs to a deleted file that is still open in some process. You can use `lsof` to look for open files, especially for deleted files.

```
lsof -nP | grep deleted
```

Comment: /disk1 is an entirely different partition and disk array than /root.